# Google Python Speech Recognition with wake word

Tags: python, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I am using the Google python speech recognition on a Raspberry Pi and it works really well. However, it is constantly listening and I would prefer to have a wake word so that it only listens when I need it to.

At the moment it listens until there is a silence (or a return to whatever the ambient background noise is) and then sends the sound clip to the API for speech to text recognition. Is there a way for me to shorten the length of time that it is listening? This way it can be listening to only one word at a time and waiting for whatever wake word I have set.

Answer (score 4):

It's better to implement the wake-word detection offline. Have a look at [Snowboy](http://docs.kitt.ai/snowboy/). They let you upload a few recordings of your wake word and you can get a trained model that you can then include in your application.

Comment: Thank you this works well. I would like to start up the google speech recognition after snowboy has detected the "wake word". To do this I need to terminate the snowboy detector and free up the microphone. This works well once but then I can't seem to restart the snowboy detector after the Google speech recognition has done its thing. The error I keep getting is "Segmentation fault". Would you know how I could restart the snowboy detector?

Comment: Are you creating a new Snowboy instance each time it's needed? You cannot call `start()` after calling `terminate()`.

Comment: I am creating a new instance each time and then calling start after the new instance is created. I think that is where it fails because I haven't released the microphone from the Google Speech recognition. (I'm not sure how to terminate that). Do you know if there is a way I can record until silence using the snowboy instance? Then I would never have to terminate.

Comment: I ended up needing to use the python function del to completely get rid of the previous instance. Terminate doesn't destroy it completely.