# 'hey siri' like hotword in command line python application

Tags: python, terminal, console-application, speech-recognition

I am creating a python based command-line personal assistant using speech_recognition and google gTTS libraries. My current implementation of the hotword 'Hey Siri' is constantly running a while loop and listening in each loop.

But it is slow and not really continuous. Therefore it misses out on speech many a times, is there a better alternative?

```
while True:
    listen()

def listen():
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = Listen.r.listen(source)
    try:
        recog_speech = str(Listen.r.recognize_google(audio))
        if 'Hey Siri' in recog_speech:
            print('I am listening')
            #listen and do stuff

    except Exception as e:
        print('Something bad happened')
```

A possible solution to solve the problem would be to **not run the loop when not spoken**.

Comment: Have you had a look at the [Troubleshooting](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/) section of the documentation? Maybe it's trying to recognize too much, which, via internet, would obviously slow things down and cause misses. Are you sure it starts recognition on speech only?

Comment: It always runs, whether it detect speech or not, returning an exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Python Speech Recognition with wake word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44639836/google-python-speech-recognition-with-wake-word)

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment by @handle,
a solution to not pick up background noise and avoid running the loop unnecessarily would be to set the energy threshold as per speechrecognition docs at  [SpeechRecogntion pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/) which was my case. 
Also I had to adjust input level of my microphone in Linux to not amplify input.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
r.energy_threshold = 4000
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this worked:

```
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    #Calibrates the microphone to differentiate ambient noise from the voice
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    print("Aguardando por comandos de voz...")
    audio = r.listen(source)
```